# In Firefox, when i open a new tab to the same website the 3rd tab is asking me to enter login credentials again

Tags: browser, tabs

My application is a J2EE web application running using Jetty server. when I login to the application and open a 2nd tab, it shows automatically the application without asking for login credentials. But, when I open 3rd tab, it is asking for login/password again. The same works fine in IE.

How to make the 3rd, 4th tab work without asking for login credentials when I am already logged in the same browser ?

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue. The session was getting invalidated in the login service when opening a new tab in the browser. We removed Session.invalidate() and that fixed the issue.

When an application is logged in with a user and password, then opening a tab in the same browser with same application url will automatically takes us to the application without asking for user, password. This is browser behavior. All browsers support this.